# Fragment .remove() .replace() and then rotate + back button crashes the app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, back-stack

I have on `onActivityResult()` this:

```
if(fm.findFragmentByTag("CARS")!=null)
                {
                    ft.remove(fm.findFragmentByTag("CARS"));
                    ft.replace(R.id.main_content_frame, cFr, "CARS");
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
```

Because I want to reload the `CarsFragment cFr` after adding a new Car to the db. Suppose the next app use:

Home -> Cars -> AddNewCar (form filled OK) -> Cars (with reloaded data) -> [back button] -> Home

That works perfectly. But:

Home -> Cars -> AddNewCar (form filled OK) -> Cars (with reloaded data) -> **[rotate]** -> [back button] -> --CRASH--

Will crash the app because of a `NullPointerException` thrown by `PopFromBackStack()`.

Any ideas? I mean, when I rotate the screen, **what happens with the BackStack?** Because if I don't rotate, everything works fine. If I rotate the screen after the first back button press (I mean, if I'm already in Home again) it keeps working alright. It's only if I rotate the Fragment after receiving the ActivityResult.

**EDIT:** Just before the `if()` I have

```
      fm.popBackStack();
      ft = fm.beginTransaction();
```

And I know already that the problem is caused by the `popBackStack();`. If I don't call this it works almost fine, except that the `CarsFragments` will be duplicated (the `.remove()` does not work, don't know why). I'm still struggling with it.

Comment: Orientation changes can kill your app; perhaps you should let the activity stay in a single orientation so that when it is rotated, it will always be landscape or vertical. By the way, since you "remove" the fragment, instead of just replacing it, I wouldn't expect it to be in the backstack right? Think about it!

Comment: I'm expecting the Fragment Home to be brought up, not the Cars Fragment that I remove AND replaced...